# is it possible to add a time limit to enter an input to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to add a time limit to a batch file to enter an input for example:

```
@echo off

echo.
echo.
set /p m=press 1: 
if %m%==1 (
goto start
)

:start 
echo hello
pause >nul

:fail
you have failed!
pause >nul
```

Could you put any code near the `set /p m=press 1:` so that if no input is entered within 10 seconds then it would go to fail?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `CHOICE` command you can do that :

```
CHOICE /T 5 /C yn /D y
```

This will automatically answer `y`after 5 secondes without user input

Comment: To the OP: type `choice /?` to get help on the command in Vista and higher.